# Unusual hashset implementation: access a random element?

Tags: c#, data-structures, hashset

*Background:* In my program I have a list of nodes (a class I have defined). They each have a unique id number and a non-unique "region" number. I want to randomly select a node, record its id number, then remove all nodes of the same region from the list.

*Problem:* Someone pointed out to me that using a hashset instead of a list would be much faster, as a hashset's "order" is effectively random for my purposes and removing elements from it would be much faster. **How would I do this (i.e. how do I access a random element in a hashset?** I only know how to check to see if a hashset contains an element I already have)?

Also, I'm not quite sure how to remove all the nodes of a certain region. Do I have to override/define a comparison function to compare node regions? Again, I know how to remove a known element from a hashset, but here I don't know how to remove all nodes of a certain region.

I can post specifics about my code if that would help.

Comment: The order of elements in a hashset is unspecificed, not random.

Comment: Perhaps adding the actual code might help you get quicker and better answers. Cheers!

Comment: @CodesInChaos It is governed by the hash right? But for my purposes that is effectively random, since it is not easily relatable to the order in which I added it.

Comment: "I can post specifics about my code if that would help." It usually does.

Comment: @Silverstaff "Random" means "can be in any order" - there is a defined order to the items; it's just not easily determinable.

Comment: @Silverstaff No, it's not "effectively random".  Being random means that there would be fixed odds of a particular item being at a particular position (whether it be evenly distributed, following a normal distribution, etc.) whereas here the order is simply indeterminate.  You cannot *rely* on the items being "randomized", but nor can you rely on them being in any particular order either.  The specifics of how they are ordered is an implementation detail subject to change at any time.

Comment: If selecting a random element is paramount then, no, a List is much faster than a HashSet.  HashSet.First() is fast and random, but probably not random enough :)

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, the order items in a HashSet isn't *random*, it's just not easily *determinable*.  Meaning if you iterate a hash set multiple times the items will be in the same order each time, but you have no control over what order they're in.

That said, `HastSet<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>` so you *could* just pick a random number `n` and remove the nth item:

```
// assuming a Random object is defined somewhere (do not declare it here)
n  = rand.Next(hashSet.Count);
var item = hashSet.ElementAt(n);
hashSet.Remove(item);
```

> Also, I'm not quite sure how to remove all the nodes of a certain region. Do I have to override/define a comparison function to compare node regions?

Not necessarily - you'll need to scan the hashSet to find matching items (easily done with Linq) and remove each one individually.  Whether you do that by just comparing properties or defining an equality comparer is up to you.

```
foreach (var dupe in hashSet.Where(x => x.Region == item.Region).ToList()) 
    hashSet.Remove(dupe);
```

Note the `ToList` which is necessary since you can't modify a collection while iterating over it, so the items to remove need to be stored in a *different* collection.

Note that you *can't* override `Equals` in the Node class for this purpose or you won't be able to put multiple nodes from one region in the hash set.

If you haven't noticed, both of these requirements defeat the purpose of using a `HashSet` - A `HashSet` is faster only when looking for a known item; iterating or looking for items based on properties is no faster than a regular collection.  It would be like looking through the phone book to find all people whose phone number start with `5`.

If you *always* want the items organized by region, then perhaps a `Dictionary<int, List<Node>>` is a better structure.

Comment: Isn't it still faster to remove items though? So overall it would be faster? Also, if I only hash-randomize once each time the program runs, will it use a different hash each time? Then I can just use hashSet.First() and it will effectively be random.

Comment: To actually remove them would be faster, but you have to _find_ the item first.  That process may eat up all of the time saved in the removal.

Comment: "Then I can just use hashSet.First() and it will effectively be random." No - the items are **not stored randomly** - you just can't determine the order.  Calling `First()` on the same hash set will _always_ give you the same result.  And removing an item does not guarantee that a "random" item form the list will be "first".

Comment: Ok so as long as I remove the element the first time I access it, it will be effectively random right?

Comment: No - the list is not reordered when you remove an item.  It's basically an array, but the position of an item in the array is determined by its hash code (which does not change).  Looking up items by position is _much_ faster than scanning, which is why `HashSet` is faster at looking for _known_ items..

Comment: Sorry I am phrasing this really badly. I access elements one at a time and remove them immediately. So even though the order doesn't change, I don't *know* the order and it is relatively 'random' compared to the order in which I added the elements. So each First() element, when I see it, appears effectively 'random'.

Comment: It depends on how the items are created (and if `GetHashCode` is overridden). If the items are created and added at the same time, they will probably not be "random".  If `GetHashCode` is not overidden then the hash code is based on the object's reference, which (based on tests) seems to be sequential for objects created at roughly the same time.  It's the same often enough that I would not call it "random" at all.

Answer (score 0):

There's another alternative approach that you could take that could end up being faster than removals from hash sets, and that's creating a structure that does your job for you in one go.

First up, to give me some sample data I'm running this code:

```
var rnd = new Random();

var nodes =
    Enumerable
        .Range(0, 10)
        .Select(n => new Node() { id = n, region = rnd.Next(0, 3) })
        .ToList();
```

That gives me this kind of data:

[image: source]

Now I build up my structure like this:

```
var pickable =
    nodes
        .OrderBy(n => rnd.Next())
        .ToLookup(n => n.region, n => n.id);
```

Which gives me this:

[image: pickable]

Notice how the regions and individual ids are randomized in the lookup. Now it's possible to iterate over the lookup and take just the first element of each group to get both a random region and random node id without the need to remove any items from a hash set.

I wouldn't expect performance to be too much of an issue as I just tried this with 1,000,000 nodes with 1,000 regions and got a result back in just over 600ms.

Answer (score -1):

On a hashset you can use ElementAt

```
notreallrandomObj nrrbase = HS.ElementAt(0);
int region = nrrbase.region;
List<notreallrandomObj> removeItems = new List<notreallrandomObj>();

foreach (notreallrandomObj nrr in HS.Where(x => x.region == region)) 
    removeItems.Add(nrr);
foreach (notreallrandomObj nrr in removeItems)
    HS.Remove(nrr);
```

Not sure if you can remove in the loop.
You may need to build up the remove list.

Yes remove O(1) on a HashSet but that does not mean it will be faster than a List.  You don't even have a solution and are optimizing.  That is premature optimization.

With a List you can just use RemoveAll

```
ll.RemoveAll(x =>  x.region == region);
```

Comment: "Not sure if you can remove in the loop." - you can't.

Comment: @DStanley Then need to build up then remove.  I was going to test.